# Elasticsearch query with nested aggregations causing out of memory

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch installed with 16gb of memory. I started using aggregations, but ran into a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error when I attempted to issue the following query:

```
POST /test-index-syslog3/type-syslog/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "DstCountry",
           "query": "CN"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "whatever": {
            "terms": {
                "field" : "SrcIP"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "destination_ip": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field" : "DstIP"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "port" : {
                            "terms": {
                                "field" : "DstPort"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query_string itself only returns 1266 hits so I'm a bit confused by the OOM error.

Am I using aggregations incorrectly? If not, what can I do to troubleshoot this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are loading the entire `SrcIP`-, `DstIP`-, and `DstPort`-fields into memory in order to aggregate on them. This is because Elasticsearch un-inverts the entire field to be able to rapidly look up a document's value for a field given its ID.

If you're going to largely be aggregating on a very small set of data, you should [look into using docvalues](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/disk-based-field-data-a-k-a-doc-values/). Then a document's value is stored in a way that makes it easy to look up given the document's ID. There's a bit more overhead to it, but that way you'll leave it to the operating system's field cache to have the relevant pages in memory, instead of having to load the entire field.

Comment: Thanks Alex! This looks like the right approach, thanks for the link it was very helpful. Sounds like I need to identify the specific fields that I'll be using to create stats, then mark them as "format": "doc_values". That'll take some planning, but I think this gets me going in the right direction. Thanks much!

Comment: Just got the above fields (and a few more) over to a new index using doc_values for the field data. Ran the above query, and it came through! Took about 5 seconds though. After 2 seconds of waiting I was sure things were exploding, but that's how it goes. ;)

Comment: Well now that I've got more data in there it's running out of memory again. Same java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space errors. Here is my mapping, am I doing something wrong here? http://pastebin.com/XBMivWGT

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the mapping of course, but looking at the value the field DstCountry can be non_analyzed. Than you could replace the query by a filter within the aggregate. Maybe that helps.

Also check if the fields you use in your aggregation are of type non_analyzed.