# Are there known limits on nested aggregations in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, aggregation, nested

Has anyone had experience hitting out of memory exceptions when nesting too many aggregations and subaggregations in Elasticsearch? I am searching over a small amount of data, but nesting more than four aggregations on top of each other seems to fail frequently.

I have also wondered whether the query filters applied at the top level of aggregation actually apply to the lowest levels of aggregation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255854/elasticsearch-query-with-nested-aggregations-causing-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the *cardinality* of each aggregation over the enter dataset matters for performance, regardless of the filter criteria. So if I bucket by variables `x` and `y`, and there are 10,000 values of `x` and 10,000 values of `y` in the dataset, that will cause massive performance issues even if only 3 values of `x` and 3 values of `y` are selected by the filter criteria.

Comment: which version is this ? Is it still a issue for ES 1.7 ? or even 1.4? Thanks